# EJS, Express, Node - can't get js or css to load

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to use EJS, Node, and Express (new to all three). Here is my ejs file, my app.js file, and directory structure. Can you please help me understand how to setup things properly? Thanks in advance.

**ejs file:**

```
   <html>
  <head>
    <script href="/javascripts/main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheer" href="/stylesheets/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    test
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

**file structure:**

```
template_1
 > bin
 > node_modules
 > public
      > images
      > javascripts
          | main.js
      > stylesheets
          | style.css
 > routes
 > views
      | index.ejs
 | app.js
 | gulpfile.js
 | package.json
```

Comment: Try replacing your line when you define the public directory to just `app.use(express.static('public'));`

Comment: OR app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/')));

Comment: @JoshuaTerrill - To confirm do you mean replace this line? 
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); I tried it but it is still not working.

Comment: Yes.... that line (had to put .... to fill up minimum character requirement)

Comment: ok perhaps I forgot to restart, cause now it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried @JoshuaTerrill solution and it works (restart your app).